# Lombok @Value with public no-args constructor

Tags: java, lombok

I have the below `Occurrence` class, i added the `@Value` annotation to make it immutable, and i set extraPrivate to true for to add a private no-args constructor.

```
@Builder
@Value
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Occurrence {
  .....
}
```

**lombok.config**

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.getter.noIsPrefix = true
lombok.noArgsConstructor.extraPrivate = true
```

Is there a way to add a **public no-args constructor** ?

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate the class `@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)`. Using just `@NoArgsConstructor` will cause a compiler error, because `@Value` makes the fields final.

From the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor).

> `@NoArgsConstructor` will generate a constructor with no parameters. If this is not possible (because of final fields), a compiler error will result instead, unless `@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)` is used, then all final fields are initialized with 0 / false / null.

Also note that:

> For fields with constraints, such as `@NonNull` fields, no check is generated, so be aware that these constraints will generally not be fulfilled until those fields are properly initialized later.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, Lombok `@NoArgsConstructor` will generate a `no arguments/default constructor`, by default generated constructor will be `public`.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NoArgsDemo {

  private Long id; 
  private String username;
}
```

From the docs,

> @NoArgsConstructor will generate a constructor with no parameters. If this is not possible (because of final fields), a compiler error will result instead, unless @NoArgsConstructor(force = true) is used, then all final fields are initialized with 0 / false / null.

Reference link: [Lombok NoArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)